# Is sympy pretty printing broken in new jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, sympy, jupyter

I have previously used pretty printing of math in the ipython notebook. After upgrading to jupyter (also upgrades many other ipython-related packages), pretty printing no longer works like before. I use this code in the top of my notebooks to set it up:

```
import sympy as sp
sp.init_printing()
```

I have also tried this with the `use_latex=True` and `use_latex='mathjax'` arguments to `init_printing`, but that does not help. In all cases, expressions are printed in plain text after upgrading. See https://gist.github.com/josteinbf/78dae5085dec0aa19a48#file-sympy_pp-ipynb for a complete example in the form of a notebook.

There are no error messages or warnings, neither in the notebook nor in the console running jupyter. How to fix (or at least debug) this problem?

Comment: That's not a plain text. I think it is working. https://imgur.com/RxMbDkF

Comment: @SudhanshuMishra: It has indeed formatted the output somewhat, but it is not what I had before. Check out this example notebook for an example of how it looked before, and how I want it to look: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/yenlung/ipython/blob/rel-0.13/docs/examples/notebooks/sympy.ipynb

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I also encountered this issue, the fix is to upgrade your `sympy` version. I found that 0.7.6 reproduces the error, but 0.7.7 has it fixed. At the moment this isn't available via `pip`, but can be found via the [github repo](https://github.com/sympy/sympy).

Comment: thank you! 0.7.6.1 seems to work as of today via doing a pip upgrade for anyone else who comes across this.

Comment: As aaron said, running `pip install -U sympy` pulls in `sympy-0.7.6.1` in which LaTeX printing works.