# Can I integrate MathJax into a Python program?

Tags: python, mathjax

This might be a silly question, but is it possible to merge MathJax into Python code? Many times I've wished the program output would look more neat, and honestly MathJax looks awesome.

I know MathJax runs on Javascript, yet I have not given up hope. If the answer is no, are there some simple modules to use instead?

For example, if:

```
1.234 / e^23 [and] (I^-)_(aq) +I _(2(s)) -> (I^-)_3(aq)
```

could be formatted as:

[image: Formatting example],

that would be ideal.

Comment: What do you mean by program output? A GUI? Your command line?

Comment: @rawbeans, either would suffice :). GUI might even be preferred (tkinter, for instance).

Comment: Are you using ipython/Jupyter notebooks? Have you looked into sympy?  Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20979993/how-to-pretty-print-in-ipython-notebook-via-sympy-pprint-only-prints-unicode-ve) and [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20979993/how-to-pretty-print-in-ipython-notebook-via-sympy-pprint-only-prints-unicode-ve)

Comment: @michael_j_ward: Valid question, I am actually using [Thonny](http://thonny.cs.ut.ee/), since I am very new to programming :) I do appreciate the links!

Comment: @armatita: do not format names of software as 'code'. Only format `actual code` as code.

Comment: @RadLexus I appreciate the guidance although I'm not sure I agree. The code tag is the best way to highlight specific keywords relevant to the question. I usually recommend its use since I find it easier to read that way (although I agree its essentially a preference).

Comment: @armatita: it is a preference - not a personal one, but of Stack Overflow itself. See for example http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266241/2564301

Comment: @RadLexus I would hardly call it a Stack Overflow directive though, as I previously said, I do understand your point. Also notice that the main argument of that user was that it messed with the vertical space between lines which is a very solvable technical issue. In any case this is not an appropriate place to discuss it. I might happen that I eventually attempt this discussion on meta. Thank you for the heads up.

Comment: I draw the math formula with plotlab, refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58496145/6521116)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can only presume that maybe you want to output something to the display for printing. Hence the common usage in Python is probably Matplotlib (albeit Gnuplot is a good alternative that is python compatible).
If you create a blank plot using Matplotlib then you can input normal plain LaTeX maths instructions (near identical to MathJax):

A small example:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import pylab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc

plt.clf()
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (8, 5)
plt.rc('font', **{'family':'serif', 'serif':['Computer Modern Roman'], 'size': 16})
plt.axis("off")
plt.text(0.5, 0.5, "Maths $e = mc^2$")
```

gives the following output

[image]

which can trivially be saved, as a .pdf, and then the apparent graininess of my screenshot is removed.

Comment: Even though this seems to be what I wished for, is there a way to format text in a similar way in my command line? Just for future reference

Comment: I not sure quite what you want to achieve: I have given an example where using Python we can generate output which uses Latex formatting, and this is only really useful (In my experience) when producing figures and graphs, and I want to overlay some nicely formatted text onto them, and generally I output the results in pdf. Could you give an example of what kind of input and output you are looking for? For nicely formatted console output in Python with maths it may be worth looking into something like sympy, albeit that is far away from MathJax. @LinearChristmas

Comment: sorry for the delay. I wondered if it was indeed possible to nicely format maths in Python command line (the place where stuff goes when one uses the function print). The GUI option is what I was originally looking for; command line was more out of curiosity. I can look into these modules in the weeks to come. Thanks again for sharing your knowledge!

Comment: Perhaps *shell* is the most accurate term :)

Comment: I think then you might want to look into the `pythontex` and `sympy`. As far as I know you can't get latex to be printed to the terminal directly, you are limited by the console's graphics, which is meant to be very simple for platform portability. However, the two packages make what is printed a lot more user friendly, and similarly can automatically produce latex code using python (speaking somewhat loosely).

Answer (score 1):

Following the answer of oliversm, one can use the class mathtext of mathplotlib:

```
from matplotlib import mathtext, font_manager
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['savefig.transparent'] = True

#texFont = font_manager.FontProperties(size=30, fname="./OpenSans-Medium.ttf")
texFont = font_manager.FontProperties(size=30, family='serif', math_fontfamily='cm')

mathtext.math_to_image(r"Maths $e = mc^2$", "output.png", prop=texFont, dpi=300, format='png')
```