# how to have sympy output latex on my local Env?

Tags: python, sympy

this command output latex in online Env

```
solve(x**2 - 33*x + 20*13-14**2, x)
```

[image]

same command outputs a plaintext on my local Env.

[image]

a simpler one could be rendered successfully.

[image]

did I missing something?

Comment: keep in mind that a browser can run additional javascript code. They are using MatJax for rendering

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I integrate MathJax into a Python program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37754756/can-i-integrate-mathjax-into-a-python-program)

Comment: thanks for your comments. but I think my question is different to your link. my local env can render a simpler latex. did you run my code on your own env?

Comment: What env are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initiate session first by calling `init_session()`

> If you plan to work in an interactive calculator-type session, the `init_session()` function will automatically import everything in *SymPy*, create some common Symbols, setup plotting, and run `init_printing()`

```py
from sympy import init_session

init_session()

x = 5
solve(x**2 - 33*x + 20*13 - 14**2, x)
```