# Latex math text in PIL ImageDraw text()

Tags: python, latex, python-imaging-library, mathjax

I'm trying to annotate a few figures I created in python. So, I'm generating an image containing the specified text (using PIL ImageDraw) and concatenating it with the image. Now, I want to include a math notation into the text. Is there a way to write text in latex math when creating the image of text? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58678867/3337089) suggests a work-around by using unicode text, but I would prefer writing the text in latex directly.

MWE:

```
from PIL import ImageFont, Image, ImageDraw
from matplotlib import pyplot


def get_annotation(image_shape: tuple, title: str, font_size: int = 50):
    frame_height, frame_width = image_shape[:2]
    times_font = ImageFont.truetype('times-new-roman.ttf', font_size)
    text_image = Image.new('RGB', (frame_width, frame_height), (255, 255, 255))
    drawer = ImageDraw.Draw(text_image)
    w, h = drawer.textsize(title, font=times_font)
    drawer.text(((frame_width - w) / 2, (frame_height - h) / 2), text=title, fill=(0, 0, 0), font=times_font,
                align='center')
    annotation = numpy.array(text_image)
    return annotation

if __name__ == '__main__':
    anno = get_annotation((100, 300), 'frame $f_n$')
    pyplot.imshow(anno)
    pyplot.show()
```

I tried passing `frame $f_n$` to `title` parameter, but dollars got printed in the text image.

PS: times-new-roman.ttf can be obtained [here](https://www.freebestfonts.com/times-new-roman-font)

Comment: can you make your code reproducible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative with sympy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36249956/3337089)

```
import sympy

sympy.preview(r'frame $f_n$', dvioptions=["-T", "tight", "-z", "0", "--truecolor", "-D 600"], viewer='file', filename='test.png', euler=False)
```