# Result of calculation shown different if using print or not

Tags: python, math, jupyter-notebook, output

In a Jupyter notebook, when using

```
1 import sympy as sym, numpy as np
2 q = sym.Symbol('q')
3 print(np.power(q,2))
4 np.power(q,2)
```

the output is

```
         q**2
[Out 1]: <sup>2</sup>
```

i.e., the (last) output is displayed with pretty math (as <sup>2</sup> actually, but I could not produce this above due to the *code* formatting), while the output of `print` commands is displayed with pure text.
This difference is much more noticeable when displaying fractions, square roots, etc.

**Is there any way to force the output of a `print` command to show "pretty", the same as the result of the last line in the cell?**

Comment: This is probably a duplicate, but you are probably looking for [`IPython.display.display`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.display).

Comment: @FengyangWang - I had tried something along those lines prior to posting, but I did not get to the answer. An answer to my question is actually contained in the link you posted. But there is also more worth posting, which I will do in the other question.